# How to insert object with 2 collections into DB using mybatis

Tags: java, mybatis, postgresql-9.3, spring-mybatis

Until now I had object User with many Roles. When I was inserting it into DB, I

```
<sql id="insertUserWithRoles">
    WITH inserted_user as (
    <include refid="insertUserWithoutRoles"/>
    RETURNING id)
    insert into user_role values
    <foreach collection="user.authorities" index="index" item="role">
        <if test="index != 0">
            ,
        </if>
        ((select id from inserted_user), (select id from role where role = #{role.role}))
    </foreach>
</sql>
```

insertUserWithoutRoles looks like this:

```
<sql id="insertUserWithoutRoles">
    INSERT INTO "user" (username, password, account_non_expired, account_non_locked, credentials_non_expired, enabled)
    VALUES (#{user.username}, #{user.password},#{user.accountNonExpired},#{user.accountNonLocked},#{user.accountNonLocked}, #{user.enabled})
</sql>
```

All of this was working perfectly....until I decided to add List to user. Now I have no clue how to insert this object into DB (PGSQL) using mybatis.

My User object looks like this:

```
public class User implements UserDetails, CredentialsContainer {
    @Nullable
    private Integer id;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private boolean accountNonExpired;
    private boolean accountNonLocked;
    private boolean credentialsNonExpired;
    private boolean enabled;
    private Set<BoostmeRole> authorities;
    private List<RemovedPermission> removedPermissions;
    ...
}
```

I Did try to wrap current insert into another with as, but it was not working. My other tries are not even worth mentioning

Table for object RemovedPermission is:

```
CREATE TABLE user_removed_permission
(
    user_id         INT NOT NULL,
    permission_id   INT NOT NULL,
    expiration_time TIMESTAMP DEFAULT NULL
);
```

Comment: What is that you exactly facing problem with. inserting data in user_removed_permission?

Answer (score 0):

This code works for PostrgeSQL 10.4 and MyBatis 3.4.6

```
<insert id="create" parameterType="User">
    <selectKey keyProperty="id" keyColumn="id" resultType="int" order="BEFORE">
        SELECT nextval('users_id_seq');
    </selectKey>
    INSERT INTO users(id, name, password)
    VALUES (#{id}, #{name}, #{password});

    INSERT INTO users_roles(user_id, role_id) VALUES
    <foreach collection="roles" item="role" separator=",">
        (#{id}, (SELECT r.id FROM roles r WHERE r.name = #{role.name}))
    </foreach>;
</insert>
```